# S3 and django-storages, not recognizing credentials

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to use django-storages with heroku and S3. So I followed the tutorial from [readthedocs](http://goo.gl/mncgDC). I installed everything as it says, I took my ID and Secret Key from Amazon console, and tried the following codes:

settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key_id'
AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = 'secret_key'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket' 


from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
>>> default_storage.__class__
<class 'django.core.files.storage.DefaultStorage'>
```

I don't know if this is normal return value. I then did the following

```
default_storage.connection
```

and I get the following exception

```
NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials
```

Is there something wrong with my setup? The code is run locally. Want to test it locally first and then upload it to heroku

EDIT: I used console to manually connect to my s3 using id and secret key and worked fine. This is what I did

```
import boto
boto.s3_connect(id, key)
```

and worked. So what could be the problem?Django?

Answer (score 1):

Found the Solution. Misspelled the key varible. just changed `AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY` to `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and everything worked as it should